# Unit test for C# interview - Write a method that finds the two-character string that is repeated in the given string most times

Tags: c#

I hope it's OK to ask this question here. 
I was asked a question at the interview  - with a description in the title.
For example, for given string "ABABDCABDCDDPPABAB"  - it would return AB because it appears most times.
Even though I could answer the question - second part of the question was to write a unit test for this method, which would be able to test all possible scenarios!
Could anyone point me on how to tackle such question?

Answer (score 2):

You should answer some questions relates to proposed behavior of the function. For example:

1. What if source string is **null**?
2. What if source string is shorter than two characters?
3. What if source string contains two or more pairs of characters with the same frequency?

All of you answers you can rewrite as a test methods:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void FindMostFrequentPair_WithNull_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
{
    var pair = Utils.FindMostFrequestPair(null);
}

[TestMethod]
public void FindMostFrequentPair_WithSameFrequentPairs_ReturnsFirst()
{
    var pair = Utils.FindMostFrequestPair("ABCD");

    Assert.AreEqual("AB", pair);
}
```

and so on.

Test boundary cases, i.e. null and empty strings, strings with odd number of characters, etc. Also test obvious successful case — you function should work.

Comment: Mark, we are thinking the same. I've raised almost the same questions in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be to test the different possibilities such as:

1. Testing when AB appears the most
2. Testing when AB appears the least
3. Testing when AB appears the same amount as PA
4. Testing what happens    with unexpected input like a null string.

There are probably more options but that would need a look at the code before going into them like verifying certain methods are called etc etc